# How can methods throwing exceptions be inlined?

Tags: java, performance, exception

I'm just curious as to how it is possible for the Java JVM to sometimes inline methods that have the potential to throw exceptions.  I assume that it's possible to inline at least some such methods (such as those that have array accesses and hence the potential to throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s).  The problem I see is that if the exception actually occurs, how do you show the proper stack trace if you've inlined the method?  Since different methods can be inlined on different machines, how does inlining not break the stack trace mechanism?

Comment: In C++, inlining almost guarantees the loss of stack information. The fact that an exception stack trace is missing a frame isn't the end of the world, though; it's just an accepted consequence of inlining (and one of the reasons compilers offer debug-mode options to suppress all inlining). I don't know whether Java behaves the same or not.

Comment: I meant this to be a Java question, but interesting to know about how this works in C++ as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is the problem you envisage? Since it is the JVM itself that does the inlining, there is nothing that prevents it from remembering what it inlined where and correct for this when it constructs a stack trace to install in a Throwable object.

When an exception is <s>thrown</s>constructed, the JVM will walk the CPU stack and figure out whether each machine stack frame corresponds to interpreted bytecode, JITted code, native code from libraries and so forth. For this it refers to tables that tell which addresses in the machine code corresponds to which instructions from the bytecode (and further back to source lines, if that information is pressent in the class file). This table can perfectly well specify that a certain place in JITted code can correspond to more than one Java-level stack frame.

However, a JVM is not *required* to do this. It may also choose simply to construct stack traces with mysterious breaks in them. See the [javadoc for Throwable.getStackTrace()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29). (There is even no requirement that a JVM is able to produce stack traces *at all*).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [this document](http://www.artima.com/underthehood/exceptions.html) which explains how exception handling works in the JVM:

> Each method that
>   catches exceptions is associated with an exception table that is
>   delivered in the class file along with the bytecode sequence of the
>   method. The exception table has one entry for each exception that is
>   caught by each try block. Each entry has four pieces of information:
>   the start and end points, the pc offset within the bytecode sequence
>   to jump to, and a constant pool index of the exception class that is
>   being caught.

Comment: I'll be interested to check it out.  I was specifically asking about the interaction of inlining with exceptions, though.  It seems that if a function is inlined, stack trace info should be lost, but yet it doesn't seem to be in a Java program.

Comment: Remember that inlining in Java takes place at runtime, not compile time like C/C++, so you're not 'losing' any information.  Any information that is optimized out and needs to be retrieved can be stored in a lookup/jump table.

Comment: Wouldn't storing exception information in lookup tables cause unacceptable performance, especially for very common exceptions such as ArrayIndexOutOfBounds?